# Delay of sleeping on cortisol cycle

Tags: endocrinology, sleep, circadian-rhythms

I was told that cortisol has to be measured at 9am or 4pm, because those where its peak level. But I wonder if changes on sleep patters affect the cortisol cycle.
I mean, if I usually go to sleep around 11pm, but certain day I go to sleep at 4am.

My cortisol cycle would vary according to my change in sleeping?

Probably the same question can be done using other hormones as example.